# Top of buffer cut off with larger fonts

Tags: fonts

When I increase the default font size (say, from Menlo 12 to 14), either by Options->Set Default Font or by `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 140)`, the top of the buffer becomes hidden. The visible part of the buffer starts a few lines down (depending on font size) and the actual top is hidden above the top of the window. I can move the cursor up to the top of the buffer, but it disappears above the window. `M-x beginning-of-buffer` doesn't help. If I lower the font size, it becomes visible again.

Emacs 24.5 (9.0) on OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you can reproduce it when you start Emacs from `emacs -Q` (no init file) then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe.

Comment: Thanks, Drew, I'll do that. It is easily reproducible (even though I did find a workaround -- see, below).

Comment: Turns out it's a known bug: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21016#5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a conflict with setting frame size:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '(
               (width . 150)
               (height . 52) ))
```